# Will SQL Select query select record which was inserted during Select query execution?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have one table `bookings` which contains billion records. We wrote a simple `SELECT` query to select some records from this table with some `WHERE` clauses (doesn't matter what was in `WHERE` clause. This query will take several seconds). After executing this `SELECT` query (and before it finishes), we then inserted a record in our `bookings` table (this record satisfies `WHERE` clauses of first `SELECT` query).

The question: "**Will this new record be selected when first `SELECT` query finishes its work?**"

Preferably I want answer about PostgreSQL case, but would be glad to hear about how MySQL, SQL Server and others would behave in such a situation.

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL won't see the update (except maybe some very unlikely scenarios), but I'm not sure you'll ever reliably have the update transaction visible. What behavior do you want to see?

Comment: Postgresql doesn't see any changes made after select started.  At least by default (read_committed isolation level).  See here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Will this new record be selected when first SELECT query finishes its work*

No.

Every statement is an atomic operation, and sees a consistent state (=snapshot) of the database as it was at the moment when the statement started.

The above applies to Postgres and Oracle (maybe to other DBMS as well, but I can't say for sure. Some support dirty reads, where this wouldn't be guaranteed)